# Python xlwings - issue with opening books all of a sudden

Tags: python, xlwings

I've been using a script that's been working for ages.  Simply opens a book:

```
bName = some book name (without the .xls)
wbookObj = xlw.Book('T:\\XYZ\\ABC\\' + bName + '.xls')
```

This has been working with no issues for a month or two, but all of a sudden my script freezes there, with no error.  I first tried running through the xlwings addin, and it would freeze.  Then I ran in Jupyter, where I hoped to see an error, but nothing. It just hangs and keeps running, doing nothing....

I realize this is kind of vague, but it's not giving me much to work with.... 
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Apparently, if you have multiple excel instances open, if any of them have a popup window active (for example, that "do you want to update links" thing) it'll restrict xlwings from opening any book (regardless if that book is the one with the popup or not)